# std::optional & compilers - shouldn't this crash?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a hiearchy of classes in which parts are optional. I would like things to automatically be created as soon as variables are set.

For that I use C++17 std::optional feature.

Now in the example below I forgot to set the "parent" (test2_inst) first, yet g++, clang and msvc all compile and run fine altough with the "not set" output.

My questions now are: am I indeed doing the wrong thing in this example? and what would the proper way of resolving this?
Or are the compilers doing the wrong thing?

```
#include <optional>

class test1 {
public:
        class test2 {
        public:
                int a, b;

                class test3 {
                public:
                        int c, d;
                };

                test3 test3_inst;
        };

        std::optional<test2> test2_inst;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        test1 *test1_inst = new test1();

        // can set value
        test1_inst->test2_inst->test3_inst.c = 3;

        // yet optional says it is note set?
        if (test1_inst->test2_inst.has_value())
                printf("set\n");
        else
                printf("not set\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using uninitialized variable, which is undefined behavior. That means anything can happen, including correct behavior.

Comment: @vll which variable is uninitialized?

Comment: All the memory is stored inside the optional, it's not heap allocated. So you're not going to get a segfault if it's nullopt if the compiler allows it. But the data in there will be incorrect

Comment: Semi-related: **Nothing** in C++ is ever guaranteed to crash, so asking *"shouldn't this crash?"* is always wrong

Comment: @UnholySheep Off topic: by default, `std::terminate` calls `std::abort` which is considered a crash. It is well defined that if you don't catch an exception then `std::terminate` will be called, so C++ some things are warranted to crash your program.

Comment: @vil `s/correct/intended/` (by definition, there is no "correct" behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't this crash?

Could.  Undefined behavior can do anything.  Crashing is one possibility.  Not crashing and appearing to work is also a possibility.

> am I indeed doing the wrong thing in this example?

Yes.

> what would the proper way of resolving this?

Depends what you are trying to do.  Check the optional...

```
if (test1_inst->test2_inst)
    test1_inst->test2_inst->test3_inst.c = 3;
```

Or, assign its value...

```
test1_inst->test2_inst = test1::test2{1, 2, {3, 4}};
```

> Or are the compilers doing the wrong thing?

No, the C++ standard gives the compilers a lot of latitude.

C++ is not a nanny language, and gives programmers enough rope to shoot themselves in the foot.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of optional::operator* and optional::operator-> is undefined if the `optional` does not contain a value.

> Accesses the contained value.
>
> 1. Returns a pointer to the contained value.
> 2. Returns a reference to the contained value.
>
> The behavior is undefined if `*this` does not contain a value.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*